# Safari can't connect to the server (nginx,unicorn,ubuntu,rails,mysql)

Tags: nginx, unicorn, server-name

I am trying to open my webpage http://moneytree.space/catalogs/traders but I got:

[image]

The unicorn and nginx are running. My working directory is /home/zhall/zoulfia

```
   root@moneytree:/home/zhall/zoulfia# rails s -e production
      => Booting Unicorn
      => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on        

       http://localhost:3000

      => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

      => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

When I typed :

[image]

In my /etc/nginx/sites-avalable/default file I got:

[image]

Do I need to change server_name to localhost? I am new to all these configuration, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
Maybe my server shuts down because there are some errors. I do not know where to hunt them down. My log file is empty :(

I check nginx configuration:

```
 sudo nginx -t
 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I boot webrick:

```
Zoulfias-iMac:zoulfia zoulfiahall$ rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-07-10 17:08:38] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-10 17:08:38] INFO  ruby 2.2.0 (2014-12-25) [x86_64-darwin13]
[2015-07-10 17:08:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18631 port=3000
```

I have no problem starting my app.

When Unicorn server boots up, I get:

```
 root@moneytree:/home/zhall/zoulfia# rails s -p80 -e production
 => Booting Unicorn
 => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://localhost:80
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
root@moneytree:/home/zhall/zoulfia#    ------> this line should not be here!
```

How do I set up application logging to see errors?

Comment: I don't see `nginx` in your `netstat` results, and if I try to `telnet` to port 80 on your server, I get `Connection refused`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What does this mean? What do I need to do to correct it. What are the likely errors that can cause this to occur?

Comment: I think there's an issue with your nginx configuration. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859653/nginx-not-running-with-no-error-message). You may also want to try posting on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

I did something very silly. I checked my /home/zhall/zoulfia/config file and saw that unicorn.rb file is there. I deleted the file and run the server again. It works now. Something tells me that this is not the end.... and I will be back with some other questions.